# Handling iOS push notifications when the app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have an app that receives PN from a backend using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Basically, all I what to do is store some data of the PN with CoreData. I’m using `application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` to do it. I tested the feature in foreground and background, opening the app with the PN and with the app icon. Everything works fine. But the problem is in this two cases:

- When the app is killed, a PN arrives, and the user taps on the push notification.
- When the app is killed, a PN arrives, and the user taps on the app icon.

I saw that sometimes, `didReceiveRemoteNotifications` is fired. Sometimes, it doesn’t. I read that this method is not called when the app is killed but I’m experiencing a different behaviour.
Also, I read that the way to handle push notifications in killed state is with VoIP apps or with `UNNotificationServiceExtension`. My app is not a VoIP app… Anyone knows if `UNNotificationServiceExtension` can resolve my problem?
This is the payload fired by the backend:

```
const message = {
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps : {
        'content-available' : 1,
        alert: {
          title : "Game Request",
          body : "Bob wants to play poker",
        }
     },
    },
  },
  data: {
    shortText: 'test',
    chasisNumber: '23',
    alertType: 'some alert type',
    alertId: '1234',
    alertTypeId: '1234',
    userId: '1234',
    text: 'some text',
    title: 'some title',
    deleted: 'false',
    creationDate: '2011-11-02T02:50:12.208Z',
    receivedDate: '2011-11-02T02:50:12.208Z',
    actionType: 'some action type',
    ticketId: '1234',
    status: 'some status'
  },
  tokens: [androidToken, iosToken]
};
```

Comment: I read that the way to handle push notifications in killed state is with VoIP apps or **with UNNotificationServiceExtension**. Do you have any document supporting your claim that push notifications in killed state can be handled with UNNotificationServiceExtension?

Answer (score 3):

First of all to answer your question before iOS 13 is that it was possible to handle a push via VoIP. Since iOS13 this method is no longer possible.

If your application is killed it is not possible to handle the push notification if the user does not click on the notification. If you receive a PN and the user opens the application via the phone's home screen you will not be able to access the PN data.

- If the application is killed, the user receive PN and he click on the notification to open the app; you must add the below code in the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of the `AppDelegate` to handle the PN:

```
if let remoteUserInfo = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
    self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteUserInfo)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this approach is that sometimes `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called in killed state, and if I add these lines of code, in these cases `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called twice and the notification is stored two times.

Comment: Yes, it works, but sometimes the method is called twice: 1. fired to handle the remote notification, 2. fired manually when didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called. However, I did a workaround: I check the GCM message ID. If it's the same as the previously stored notification -> do not store it in the database.

Comment: Good! If the answer helped you, accept it or upvote it :)

Comment: Yes of course! Just for curiosity... Do you know how famous apps handle this situation?

Comment: Whatsapp before iOS 13 to prevent a voice or video call without using VOIP, it sent the user a notification every 5 seconds (which replaces the previous notification) until the user picked up. Now they are going to VOIP

Comment: Ok! I'll upvote your answer. If nothing more is received, I'll make it as accepted :) Thanks!